# How to set Header/Footer fix height and text for all pages runtime creating PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating PDF from my DataTable using iTextSharp version 5.3.5 in asp.net c#. My DataTable contain unkown rows, sp while PDF generating if it take more then one page i need to fix some header and footer for each page

**Code**:

```
public DataTable dataTable;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        dataTable = getData();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 90, 10);
        string path = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + "/Doc103.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        CreatePages(document);
        document.Close();
 }

private void CreatePages(Document document)
    {
        document.NewPage();
        document.Add(FormatPageHeaderPhrase(dataTable.TableName));
        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataTable.Columns.Count);
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
        pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100; // percentage
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 2;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            pdfTable.AddCell(column.ColumnName);
        }
        pdfTable.HeaderRows = 1;  
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (object cell in row.ItemArray)
            {
               pdfTable.AddCell(cell.ToString());
            }
        }

        document.Add(pdfTable);
    }

    private static Phrase FormatPageHeaderPhrase(string value)
        {
            return new Phrase(value, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(255, 0, 0)));
        }
```

**Screenshoot of PDF:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the below links:

- [Creating PDFs with iTextSharp](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext.aspx)
- [Code sample for using iTextSharp PDF library, by Massoud Mazar](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx)

Comment: for that best of luck dude

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to solve this.

One of them, is by using page events. You create a page event implementing the OnEndPage() method. If `writer.PageNumber > 1`, you add a header, for instance like this:

```
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, "Continued from previous page", 36, 820, 0);
```

See the examples from [chapter 5](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/) for more info about page events.

Another way to solve this, is by introducing a table header: `table.HeaderRows = 1;` so that the first row is repeated (make sure that row contains a cell that spans all columns saying "Continued from previous page"). To avoid that this header appears on the first page, use `table.SkipFirstHeader = true;`